# What should I use for periodic operations in asp net core 3.1?

Tags: timer, asp.net-core-3.1, asp.net-core-hosted-services

I need to start an async method that will do some work every hour, but I'd like to find out better way, then just run IHostedService and run timer in Start method.

Comment: As @fbede already mentioned, if you don't like to implement it yourself on top of `IHostedService` or `BackgroundService` then take Hangfire. I use it extensive and it can run jobs immediately, scheduled or recurring. All you need. But you need a Sql or Redis Database, so it can store its information. If this would be to much for your case, you have to work with `IHostedService`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io/). It's a robust, open source (and the most popular for ASP.NET) library for managing background processing.